# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers converging to $0,$ then $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n}a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a monotone decreasing sequence of positive real numbers converging to $0.$ I want to prove that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n}a_n$ converges.

**MY TRIAL**

My idea is to use the sequence of partial sums and use monotone convergence criterion. Let \begin{align}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n}_{k=1}(-1)^{k}a_k\end{align}

**MONOTONICITY**

For even terms, let $n=2m+1.$ Then, 
\begin{align}s_{2m+3}&=s_{2m+1}+a_{2m+2}-a_{2m+3}\\&=s_{2m+1}+(a_{2m+2}-a_{2m+3})\end{align}
Since 
\begin{align}a_{n+1}\leq a_{n},\;\forall\;n\in\;\Bbb{N}\end{align}
then 
\begin{align}a_{2m+2}-a_{2m+3}\geq 0\end{align}
Therefore, \begin{align}s_{2m+3}\geq s_{2m+1},\;\forall\;m\in\;\Bbb{N}\end{align}
So, $\{s_{2m+1}\}$ is a non-decreasing sequence.

**BOUNDEDNESS**

\begin{align}s_{2m+1}&=\sum^{2m+1}_{k=1}(-1)^{k}a_k\\&=-(a_1-a_2)-(a_3-a_4)-\cdots-(a_{2m-1}-a_{2m})-a_{2m+1}\\&\leq-a_{2m+1}\end{align}
Since $\{s_{2m+1}\}$ is a non-decreasing sequence, bounded above. Then, by monotone convergence theorem, it converges. Let
\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_{2m+3}=s\end{align}
If $n$ is even, say $n=2m+2$, then the sum of the first $n$ terms is
\begin{align}s_n\equiv s_{2m+2}=s_{2m+1}+a_{2m+2}\end{align}
By hypothesis $a_n\to 0$, as $n\to \infty,$ so that 
\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{2m+2}=0\end{align}
and as $m\to \infty,$
\begin{align}s_n\equiv s_{2m+2}=s_{2m+1}+a_{2m+2}\to s\end{align}
Therefore, 
\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_{n}=s\end{align}

Kindly check, I'm I correct? If no, corrections are highly welcome! If I am totally wrong, alternative proofs or counterexamples will be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: @Riemann: The series in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test, starts from $n=0$ but mine starts from $n=1.$ Kindly compare. Thanks!

Comment: it is not essential distinct!

Comment: you can check your proof compare with  Wikipedia's proof .

Comment: Dear Downvoter, why the downvote? I wrote this proof myself! Check the content, they are very different from wikipedia or other posts!

Comment: what  you prove is a well-known  theorem, and you does not give a different proof。They are, perhaps, similar in content, but not in form。

Comment: @Riemann: Thanks for that! Similar, but not in form!

Comment: Do know $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n}a_n$ and $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^{n}a_n$ has the same convergence?

Comment: @Riemann: I am just realizing that! Finite terms shouldn't affect convergence. My book already proved for $n=0$ but I am solving $n=1$ as an exercise.

Comment: If you think your exercise makes sense, just do it.

Comment: @Riemann: Thanks!